# How to provide a StaticResource as value to class like for <GridViewColumnHeader>?

Tags: wpf, xaml

When I provide a ColumnHdr1 as attribute of a class like header, it works.

```
<GridView>
    <GridViewColumn Header="{StaticResource ColumnHdr1}" Width="200" 
</GridView>
```

But how to provide it in the syntax when its the value of the item as in below?

```
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}">
                    <GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <GridViewColumnHeader>{StaticResource ColumnHdr1}</GridViewColumnHeader>
                    </GridViewColumn.Header>

                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
```

In this case, the `{StaticResource ColumnHdr1}` itself get printed, it's not interpreted. How do I write it so it picks the string from resource?

Comment: Why do you think that second option is possible and will work?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski My instinct was use the same express I used for `Header` since it's the same header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XML tag syntax like this:

```
<GridViewColumn.Header>
    <GridViewColumnHeader>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="ColumnHdr1"/>
    </GridViewColumnHeader>
</GridViewColumn.Header>
```